# iOS (iPhone) S/MIME certificate with multiple addresses

Tags: certificates, email, iphone, smime

On an iPhone I have a mail account in the native Mail app with two distinct e-mail addresses, and a certificate that lists both of those e-mail addresses in the SAN field. When I try to send mail with one of the two addresses in the "from" field, encryption and signature work fine. When I select the other address in the "from" field, the Mail app says that it doesn't have a certificate associated with this identity.

The same certificate works fine with either address in the Mail app on a Mac.

Any hints how to further isolate the problem? The iPhone's certificate handling is so opaque that I can't really see what's going on.

More details:

The certificate is issued by DigiCert. Trust hierarchy looks fine. Two e-mail addresses that belong to me listed in the SAN field. It works perfectly on OS X's native Mail app -- I can send mail with either of the two addresses in the "from" field and digital signature and encryption both work fine.

On the iPhone, both e-mail addresses are associated with the same identity. I exported the certificate and corresponding private key on the Mac, imported it and installed it as a profile on the iPhone, and selected it as the encryption certificate and the digital signing certificate associated with the correct e-mail identity.

Comment: Steps to reproduce:
1: Get a cert with 2 e-mail addresses listed in SubjectAlternativeName field
2: in the Mail app, create an account with either one of the addresses.
3: Import the cert to the iPhone and enable signing and encryption. Everything works as expected.
4: In the Mail app, edit the account and add the other address as a 2nd e-mail address. 
5: Now, Mail will only sign and encrypt when the 2nd address is selected in the "From" field.  If the first address is selected, Mail says that it's unable to encrypt because no encryption identity is associated with that e-mail address.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems your post would better suite into the bug tracker of Apple, as it seems to be more a software defect than a security related problem.

Comment: I've just tested this with my own certificate which has been issued for 2 email addresses, and it works on iOS 15.3.1. Can you please add the contents of your certificate to the question (use `openssl x509 -text -in <certificate-file>` to print it), and please also describe how you configured Mail on your iPhone.

Comment: Did you try if it works when you perform step 4 before step 3 as in your reproduction steps? Alternatively, it may be enough to disable then re-enable encryption and signing. I suspect that the connection may be made at that very moment, and so wasn't made to the second email address, as you have added it afterwards.